# Feature file executes with an error: Expected scheme-specific part at index 10:

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber

Setting up an automation environment in Eclipse.
Created a Maven project, installed Cucumber plugin, specified all dependencies.
Now, when running feature file I am getting an error.

Shall I glue the step definition file how I did it in Intelij? I cleared the path in Glue option, but it has no effect to the current issue.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 10: classpath:
        at io.cucumber.core.model.GluePath.parseAssumeClasspathScheme(GluePath.java:64)
        at io.cucumber.core.model.GluePath.parse(GluePath.java:34)
        at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:161)
        at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:108)
        at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:101)
        at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:97)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.withArgs(Runtime.java:131)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime$Builder.withArgs(Runtime.java:127)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:22)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
    Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 10: classpath:
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at io.cucumber.core.model.GluePath.parseAssumeClasspathScheme(GluePath.java:62)
        ... 9 more


    Here are all dependencies I added into pom.xml:




          <dependencies>
           <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.13</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What were u adding in the glue option? Can u add that? Also no need for this gherkin info.cukes 2,12,2 dependency. Change the cucumber-junit dependency to 4.2.4

Comment: To Glue I added the path to the step definition file, but it was throwing another error. Changed cucumber-junit to 4.2.4 - still having this error.

Comment: Refer to this for more details - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1571

Comment: This was fixed in `4.2.5`.  Btw. You shouldn't include `gherkin`, `cucumber-jvm-deps`, `cucumber-core` or `cucumber-jvm` as dependencies. They're all transitive dependencies and will be automatically included.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same stack trace using the Cucumber plugin for Eclipse.  I had just changed from Cucumber 1.2.5 (where everything worked fine) to 4.2.4.  (Note: I also had to change the import for `DataTable` from `cucumber.api.DataTable` to `io.cucumber.datatable.*`.)

The [github page for the code](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/model/GluePath.java) where the error is occurring gives some clues.

> The glue path can be written as either a package name: {@code com.example.app},
>    a path {@code com/example/app} or uri {@code classpath:com/example/app}.

Based on this text, I suspected the "Glue:" field in the Cucumber Feature runner configuration.  The default was simply "classpath:".  When I changed this to be the package name where the step classes were located, the tests ran.

My best guess is that the old version of Cucumber was somehow able to accept "classpath:" for the Glue value, while the new version does not.